# How does a star wobble due to orbiting bodies

Tags: classical-mechanics, astrophysics, mass, measurements

What equations determine how a star wobbles in response to an orbiting planet, and can it be used to determine the mass of distant objects based on the wobble?

If there are other more reliable methods of determining mass than the one I am asking about here, I would appreciate a few links explaining these methods, or an explanation of those methods and their benefits/limitations.

Comment: What constant are you talking about? You'll have to provide a formula in which this constant appears for us to be able to understand the question.

Comment: Do you means Newtonian gravity? You might want to read up on "reduced mass" in that context which will help. If your asking about measuring these things, my answer to http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/22700/about-binary-stars-and-calculating-velocity-period-and-radius-of-their-orbit is a mediocre job of explaining the work. Maybe one of the astronomers can jump in with more detail (or point us at a migrated question that already has it).

Comment: Do I really suck that bad at asking questions.

Comment: Let me try what factors determined how a star with a common surrounding solar system lets use our system for simplicity effect the wobble of the central star again our sun for simplicity

Comment: Newtonian gravity. The star pulls planets, asteroids, comets, and other junk about in circles, right? And for every action there is an equal and opposite reaction, right?

Comment: Correct so we should be able to find mass of the star and also mass of any and all objects pulling on it as well as their location compared to the star and the speed of all of these objects. Which I wanted to lead me to asking does a black hole follow this logic even if a miniscule insignificant margin.

Comment: @Argus: The black hole wobbles just like a star, but we wouldn't see it unless there is a good source of light near the black hole that wobbles with it.

Comment: @Argus: I rewrote it hopefully keeping your intention clear. If you don't like it, roll back.

Comment: @RonMaimon: thank you for the edit. Helps bring the question into focus. One more asking because I am not sure if what I think the answer is and the true answer is. If such a system say black hole orbited by a large star. Would the mass be that of the singularity or that of the event horizon?

Comment: If anyone from MOA as there would not need to be a closeby star with the same wobble to detect useing gravitational lensing. My "end game" is determing if there is a fundamental difference between the mass of the singularity and that of the event horizon or if these two things are indistinguishable. Useing current detection methods.

Comment: @Argus: the "singularity" does not have a mass, neither does the "event horizon". The mass is a property of the whole system, and is only measured at infinity. Your question makes no sense, but at least now is a famous difficult question that makes no sense. The "singularity" is not a matter particle, the black hole is _not_ a point mass surrounded by horizon, the sooner you get rid of that idea the better.

Comment: It seems to me(this is opinion not to be taken as fact) the word infinity "an indefinitely great number or amount" is used far too often. Infinite density says to me we have not made a number for the exact density. As black holes are not all exactly the same size there must be some basic sufferance in mass and density.

Comment: @RonMaimon: by famous do you mean my first real question or has this been asked before I could not find any duplicate questions.

Comment: @Argus: It's not famous _here_, the issue of localizing mass-energy in General Relativity is a famous problem among General Relativists. You are thinking about it positivistically--- formulating an experiment to test where the mass is by the wobble of a BH in response to an orbiting body, and this is a very nice idea. But you can't find out about the localization of mass in the singularity, because it is behind the horizon. The singularity is not a point mass, it's something else more interesting than that. You can ask how the mass spreads on horizon, but for a spherical BH it must be uniform.

Comment: @RonMaimon: somehow I keep getting tied up on that it is not a point anymore. Without being too amateurish how whould I ask. Why is the matter drawn into a black hole not condensed into a single point within the singularity?

Comment: @Argus: That's a good question--- the matter does end on the singularity, but it's in the _future_, it doesn't send field out back in time. If you ask this question (in those words) and it would be upvoted and you'll surely get a good answer from somebody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycenter#Astronomy (and the links from it to find out more about the subject).

If you take our Solar System as an example and consider just the heaviest planet Jupiter, the Sun attracts Jupiter, but Jupiter attracts the Sun as well. Jupiter is much lighter than the Sun, but it's heavy enough to significantly move the Sun as it orbits. The barycentre of the Sun-Jupiter system is slightly above the Sun's surface, so an anstronomer looking at the Solar System from the planet Zogg would see the Sun orbiting (i.e. wobbling) about a point just above the Sun's surface.

To calculate the mass of the planet you need to know it's orbital period and how much the star is moving. You also need the mass of the star, but we can estimate this from the star's brightness and colour. The period of the star's wobble tells us the radius of the planet's orbit, and from that and how much the star wobbles, i.e. how much the planet moves it, we can work out the mass of the planet. The maths isn't as hard as you might think. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_spectroscopy#Procedure for the details.

You ask about other methods of determining the mass. In the Solar System we can calculate the masses of planets, asteroids etc by observing their effects on their moons, other planets etc. For exoplanets we can generally only see the star, so that's the only way we have of estimating their mass.

Comment: Sounds like this is the current way in use as yo said we can use this for smaller bodies what about larger is there an upper limit or can say the "wobble" of an entire galaxy be observed and mass calculated?

Comment: We can estimate the mass of galaxies by measuring the speeds of stars orbiting in them, or by using the virial theorem (these two methods were the first to suggest dark matter existed). In principle galaxies can orbit each other, but the orbital motion takes tens to hundreds of millions of years, so it's far too slow for us to observe.