# How to find orbital radius of star in a binary system using redshift and orbital period data?

Tags: astronomy, orbital-motion, doppler-effect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [About binary stars and calculating velocity, period and radius of their orbit](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/22700/about-binary-stars-and-calculating-velocity-period-and-radius-of-their-orbit)

I am given the non-redshifted wavelength of the EM radiation from one of the stars, the wavelengths at minimum and maximum redshift, and the interval between minimum and maximum redshift (which is presumably half the orbital period). It is assumed that the stars' orbits are on the same plane as the Earth.

How would one calculate the radius of the given star's orbit?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22700/520. Might even be a duplicate, but if it is there is a dire need for a better answer than my off-the-cuff hand-waving.

Comment: I looked at that, it didn't get me any closer to knowing what to do. Besides, from what I can see, all that's needed is a simplified model that takes no account of the velocity of the Earth.

Comment: *"from what I can see, all that's needed is a simplified model that takes no account of the velocity of the Earth"* First bullet point: subtract off the known contribution from Earth's orbital motion.

Comment: "_Remove the mean relative velocity, and find longitudinal velocity in the remote system center of mass frame as a function of time. You can also get the longitudinal size of the orbit by integrating the velocity. Compute the reduced mass and reduced radius of the orbit from Kepler's laws_" I don't really understand any of this part, though. It goes far beyond what I really need to know for this course, so my current knowledge is insufficient.